# JQuery Columnizer several Columnizer objects in a row. Expanding horizontal...How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am stuck with the JQuery columnizer plugin. I am trying to use it for several objects and order all in a row expanding to the right. So that i get a scrollbar at the bottom. I think it is more a CSS problem. I tried several wrapping methods, tested different overflow types but in the end had no success. Here is my basic Fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j1e5bcqa/)

My CSS looks like this:

```
.column p, .column h1 { padding: 5px; }
body { font-size: 9pt; }
#wrapper {  }
.wide, .thin { clear:both;
}
.wide{
    background:blue;
}
.thin{
    background:yellow;
}
```

The js is only starting columnizer:

```
$(function(){
    $('.wide').columnize({width:400,height : 400});
    $('.thin').columnize({width:400,height : 400});
});
```

I like to have the yellow columns floating to the right beside the blue. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'behind'? You want them to be overlapped? Or do you want them in a row, one after the other, with a scrollbar?

Comment: I edited my question. I meant floating to the right so that it sits on the right side beside the blue.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, columnizer statically changes the width of the .wide and .thin divs. There is no way to put them side by side other than also change the width of their container. So CSS won't cut it, you either use Javascript or (shudder) a table. So something like this:

```
  var tw=$('.thin').width();
  var ww=$('.wide').width();
  $('<div></div>').insertBefore('.wide').append($('.wide,.thin')).width(tw+ww).css('overflow-x','auto');
  $('.wide,.thin').css({display:'inline-block'})
```

after the columnizer calls.

Comment: That worked perfectly. But I am getting new problems when trying to combine this with images, wich i try to position between the blue and the yellow object. like in this fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/j1e5bcqa/5/)

Comment: Ok, setting vertical-align:top for thin wide and middle solved it now. Thanks for the help! [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j1e5bcqa/6/)